# Tooltips displaying blocks instead of Chinese Characters

Tags: character-encoding, internationalization, tinymce

using `zh-cn` for my language.

browser is Chrome, and chinese characters appear on other websites, and on other parts of this my site. i'm not sure what the problem is.

any help is appreciated :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if tooltips show up on firefox. If they do then the fix is as follows.

(assuming windows)

Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Administrative -> Change System Locale -> Change to locale you need (For me it was Chinese (Simplified).) -> Restart system

All tooltips should show up afterwords.